# Array returning NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

I'm having an issue assigning values to an array and when I later access that array slot, it returns NaN.

First, I declare the arrays like:

```
    var oldTherms = []; 
    var newTherms = [];
    var oldInputTherms;
    var newInputTherms;
```

I'm using a data set of variables to calculate a value to be assigned to the oldTherms and newTherms arrays.  I've verified that the calculation portion works and supplies an appropriate value into oldInputTherms and newInputTherms.  I also verified that the dataSet.month[i] is returning correct values.  However, the switch statement below doesn't seem to add a cumulative total to oldTherms[] or newTherms[].  When I try to access the newTherms[] or oldTherms[], the result is 'NaN'

```
switch (dataSet.month[i]){
    //subtract 1 in array slot bc months number 1-12 and array slots number 0-11
    case 1: //january
        oldTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += oldInputTherms; //add therms to the total used 
        newTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += newInputTherms;
        oldKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0; //no cooling energy calcs
        newKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0;
        break;
    case 2: //february
        oldTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += oldInputTherms; //add therms to the total used
        newTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += newInputTherms;
        oldKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0; //no cooling energy calcs
        newKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0;
        break;
    case 3: //march
        oldTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += oldInputTherms; //add therms to the total used 
        newTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += newInputTherms;
        oldKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0; //no cooling energy calcs
        newKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0;
        break;
    case 4: //april
        oldTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += oldInputTherms; //add therms to the total used 
        newTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += newInputTherms;
        oldKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0; //no cooling energy calcs
        newKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0;
        break;
    case 5: //may
        oldTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += oldInputTherms; //add therms to the total used 
        newTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += newInputTherms;
        oldKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0; //no cooling energy calcs
        newKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0;
        break;
    case 6: //june
        oldTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += oldInputTherms; //add therms to the total used 
        newTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += newInputTherms;
        oldKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0; //no cooling energy calcs
        newKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0;
        break;
    case 7:  //july
        oldTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += oldInputTherms; //add therms to the total used 
        newTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += newInputTherms;
        oldKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0; //no cooling energy calcs
        newKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0;
        break;
    case 8: //august
        oldTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += oldInputTherms; //add therms to the total used 
        newTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += newInputTherms;
        oldKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0; //no cooling energy calcs
        newKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0;
        break;
    case 9:  //sept
        oldTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += oldInputTherms; //add therms to the total used 
        newTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += newInputTherms;
        oldKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0; //no cooling energy calcs
        newKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0;
        break;
    case 10: //oct
        oldTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += oldInputTherms; //add therms to the total used 
        newTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += newInputTherms;
        oldKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0; //no cooling energy calcs
        newKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0;
        break;
    case 11: //nov
        oldTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += oldInputTherms; //add therms to the total used 
        newTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += newInputTherms;
        oldKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0; //no cooling energy calcs
        newKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0;
        break;
    case 12:  //dec
        oldTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += oldInputTherms; //add therms to the total used 
        newTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += newInputTherms;
        oldKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0; //no cooling energy calcs
        newKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0;
        break;
    default:
        oldTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0; //add therms to the total used 
        newTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0;
        oldKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0; //no cooling energy calcs
        newKwh[dataSet.month[i]-1] += 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need all those cases that do exactly the same thing?

Comment: `oldInputTherms`, `newInputTherms` are declared, but not defined

Comment: What's the point of adding `0` to everything in the `default:` case?

Comment: Put `console.log(oldInputTherms)` before the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the arrays to contain 0:

```
var oldTherms = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; 
var newTherms = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

Otherwise, you're adding `newInputTherms` and `oldInputTherms` to `undefined`, and the result of that is `NaN`.

Comment: Ah, bravo. Nice spot.

Comment: Couldn't have done it without you pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much!  Sorry for any of the confusion and I appreciate your patience.  I've only been playing around with JavaScript for a couple weeks and have so much to learn!

Answer (score 4):

> When I try to access the newTherms[] or oldTherms[], the result is 'NaN'

`oldInputTherms`, `newInputTherms` are declared, but not defined, so lines like these

```
oldTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += oldInputTherms;
newTherms[dataSet.month[i]-1] += newInputTherms;
```

will cause your NaN.

---

But, you said

> I've verified that the calculation portion works and supplies an appropriate value into oldInputTherms and newInputTherms

If this is so, then perhaps `oldTherms` and `newTherms` are not initialized correctly. If that is the case, please see Barmar's answer above.

Comment: Sorry for some of the confusion.  I assign values to oldInputTherms and newInputTherms earlier in the code.  I verified that within the switch they still hold the correct values.  I need all the case statements because I am separating them into the energy use for each month, so I'm using a 12-slotted array to hold a value for each month.

Comment: That just adds 0 to everything, which is useless. It seems like there's something missing from the code that's supposed to set these variables to something relevant.

Comment: 'useless' is a relative term. There is intermediary code we are not seeing. If the NaN goes away, then we're on the right track.

Comment: The question says that he's verified that he's putting an appropriate value into `oldInputTherms` and `newInputTherms`

Comment: Let's wait for more code from the OP, then edits will be made. How else can NaN creep into those arrays from the given code? This is a reasonable observation.

Comment: @Drakes You were close, see my answer. Right problem, wrong variables.

Comment: Bravo, +1 @Barmar. I'll update my answer to be more useful, but you can go ahead with your detailed answer.